# protobuf-net do not serialize List<T>

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I am trying to serialize `List<T>` but get empty file and `List<T>` won't serialize. I do not get any exception and read protobuf-net manual, all members which I want to serialize are marked with `[ProtoContract]` and `[ProtoMember]` atributes

```
public void Save()
{
    using (var outputStream = File.Create(SettingsModel.QueueListDataFile))
    {      
        Serializer.Serialize(outputStream, QueueList);
    }
}

[Serializable]
[ProtoContract]
public class QueueList : SafeList<QueueItem>
{

}

[Serializable]    
[ProtoContract]
public class SafeList<T> : SafeLock
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    private static readonly List<T> ItemsList = new List<T>();
}

[Serializable]
[ProtoContract]
public class QueueItem
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string SessionId { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(3)]
    public string Ip { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

protobuf-net does not look at static data; your main data is:

```
private static readonly List<T> ItemsList = new List<T>();
```

AFAIK, **no** serializer will look at that. Serializers are object-based; they are only interested in the values on an instance of an object. Beyond that, there is an issue of inheritance - you have not defined it for the model, so it is looking at each separately.

The following works fine, but frankly I suspect it would be wise to simplify the DTO model here; something as simple as a list of items should not involve 3 levels of hierarchy... in fact, it shouldn't involve **any** - `List<T>` works *just fine*.

---

```
using ProtoBuf;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        using (var outputStream = File.Create("foo.bin"))
        {
            var obj = new QueueList { };
            obj.ItemsList.Add(new QueueItem { Email = "hi@world.com" });
            Serializer.Serialize(outputStream, obj);
        }
        using (var inputStream = File.OpenRead("foo.bin"))
        {
            var obj = Serializer.Deserialize<QueueList>(inputStream);
            Console.WriteLine(obj.ItemsList.Count); // 1
            Console.WriteLine(obj.ItemsList[0].Email); // hi@world.com
        }
    }
}
[Serializable]
[ProtoContract]
public class QueueList : SafeList<QueueItem>
{

}

[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(1, typeof(SafeList<QueueItem>))]
public class SafeLock {}

[Serializable]
[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(2, typeof(QueueList))]
public class SafeList<T> : SafeLock
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public readonly List<T> ItemsList = new List<T>();
}

[Serializable]
[ProtoContract]
public class QueueItem
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string SessionId { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(3)]
    public string Ip { get; set; }
}
```