# List of object to file and back

Tags: c#, vb.net, file

How can I write a large list of type "TestClass" to a file and back. The file size doesn't matter but the performance/speed does.

```
   <Serializable>
Public Class TestClass
    Public testValue As Object
    Public testValue2 As ULong
End Class
```

I read about BinaryFormatter and it worked well until the list is larger than Int32.MaxValue. If you have like 12,000,000 entries in the last, binaryformatter raises an exception. Another problem is that one of the properties of TestClass is **type of object** where most serialization solution fails.

Comment: I do know we use Protobuf (from google) for performance critical serialization of massive amount of data, did you try that out yet ?

Comment: Yes and it fails because of testValue is type of object and it has difficuties with list of's ;-) See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13582208/protobuf-net-do-not-serialize-listt

Comment: @Baldik you can still use `BinaryFormatter` - just split your list into chunks and append serialized parts to same file

Comment: Also, there is no way to tell if it's possible to serialize an Object, what if it's a Form, a Control ? These will produce exceptions... You should put `Public testValue As ISerializable`, that way you are sure that you won't run into any exception while serializing, except for the size...