# Can Protobuf.net serialize collection?

Tags: c#, .net, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I am facing an issue where some collection I was able to serialize could not be deserialized. But some others could be.

**MySerializer.cs**

```cs
public ProtobufSerializer
{
        public string Serialize<T>(T record)
            where T : IProtobufSerializable
        {
            if (record == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(record));
            }

            using MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(stream, record, PrefixStyle.Base128);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(stream.ToArray());
        }

        public string SerializeItems<T>(T record)
            where T : IReadOnlyCollection<IProtobufSerializable>
        {
            if (record == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(record));
            }

            using MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(stream, record, PrefixStyle.Base128);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(stream.ToArray());
        }

        public T Deserialize<T>(string dataInBase64String)
            where T : IProtobufSerializable
        {
            if (dataInBase64String == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dataInBase64String));
            }

            byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(dataInBase64String);
            using MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(data);
            return Serializer.DeserializeWithLengthPrefix<T>(stream, PrefixStyle.Base128);
        }

        public IReadOnlyCollection<T> DeserializeItems<T>(string dataInBase64String)
            where T : IProtobufSerializable
        {
            if (dataInBase64String == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dataInBase64String));
            }

            byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(dataInBase64String);
            using MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(data);
            return Serializer.DeserializeWithLengthPrefix<IReadOnlyCollection<T>>(stream, PrefixStyle.Base128);
        }
}
```

In this IProtobufSerializable is a marker interface I have given to all classes where we have given protobuf-net attributes end to end.

I was not able to find documentation on how to serialize a collection.

Here a fault I am anticipating is I am trying to serialize an `IReadOnlyCollection<IProtobufSerializable>` and trying to deserialize it to the same `IReadOnlyCollection<IProtobufSerializable>`.
But is protobuf-net capable of doing this? Do we have to make a generic type or a wrapper type with Attributes assigned as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/13582592/6128864 to actually serialize and deserialize.

The collection properties I might have in any of the classes implementing `IProtobufSerializable` will already be having the required tags.

The issue we are facing is "A repeated type was not expected as an aux type" on trying to deserialize only some of the data serialized using the above `SerializeItems` method.
And this issue goes away on downgrading from `v3.0.101` to `2.4.6`.

Can anyone please explain the behavior and suggest a right way?

Comment: This seems like a bug, It is probably best reported on GitHub.

Comment: What part might be the bug is my question.?